# Which all nodes will qualify as an ancestor?

Tags: terminology, data-structures, trees

I was going through the fundamentals of tree structure and the definition for *ancestor* is as follows:

> A node u is an ancestor of v if there is a path from u to v.

[image]

Consider the node `11`. Is node `2` (not the root, the other one on the left) an ancestor of node `11`? It is strictly not a grandparent of `11`, however, there does exist a path between these nodes. This is confusing to me, because this would also imply that the sibling nodes (`5`) of `11` would qualify as an ancestor.

Comment: I am curious as to why you gave the same number to two nodes, thus creating some confusion. Was that intentional? I do not mean you intended confusion, but that you might have thought that two nodes having the same number would have a consequence on the answer to your question.

Comment: Where did you find that definition? What is the tree definition that goes along with it? The ancestor definition won't work in the intended way for every tree definition.

Comment: @Raphael This image is in [public domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#/media/File:Binary_tree.svg), hence no attribution is required. The definition can be found inside [this pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/trees.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root-2 is an ancestor of 11 (it's the great-grandparent) but you're asking about the 2 on the left, which is not an ancestor. There is no directed path from that node to 11 since the left-2 has no outgoing edges. Paths must respect the direction of the edges.  Siblings are not ancestors for the same reason.

(Sometimes, we want to talk about a path that ignores the edge directions. These are usually referred to as something like "paths in the underlying undirected graph".)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the nodes in a tree as cities and the path connecting them as roads.
If the paths are directed, the roads are one way. On a undirected tree, the roads are two way.

In the sample you have provided, there is no road from the city 2 (which is not root) to 11. So 2 is not at all related to 11 and not a parent.
But the cities 2, 7 and 6 have roads to 11. The city 6 is the most closer one (parent), 7 is bit farther (grand parent) and 2 (root node) is most farthest (great grand parent).
This distance means that, you have traverse (travel) more from root node to 11, than other existing paths.

Keep tracking of parents of a node will be helpful, especially in inserting a new node before that node and deleting the node.